# Palette Mapped Surface view or Heat Map help n GNUPLOT

Tags: imagemagick, gnuplot, image-manipulation

I have a data set of average RGB values derived from an image.  The image is 1729 x 981 and I've used imagemagick to average each 170x98 pixel section and output a CSV with the data.  this gives me 153 lines representing the 17 sections across and 9 down.

What I'm trying to achieve, and failing at, is creating basically a heat map, or pallet mapped surface view of the image with the average data shown across the 17 x 9 sections using GNUPLOT.

My assumption is that my data is formatted incorrectly.  But I also know very little about gnupolot.  So there's that.

Here is the data set I'm using.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mfhgkrdbo5xdrj/RNST_SDI_20220303_145749.DPX_DATA.csv?dl=0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the values in columns 2/3/4 represent?  They seem to lie in the range [475:540], which doesn't look at all like RGB component values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will rephrase my comment as a preliminary answer.

The form of the command you want is `plot DATA using x:y:R:G:B with rgbimage` but it is not entirely clear from your description how to derive the R/G/B components.  The range of values in columns 2/3/4 of the file you linked to contain values roughly in the range 450 - 550.  Usually the color components either run from 0.0 - 1.0 or from 0 - 255.   For the purpose of illustration I will convert yours into numbers in the range 0.0-1.0 and show the plot command.

We will derive the x and y components from the line number, ignore the content of column 1, and scale columns 2/3/4 to the range 0-1.  You don't say how you want the result marked up with pixel coordinates, titles, or the like so I just leave everything to default.

```
 set datafile separator comma       # it's a csv file
 set rgbmax 1.0                     # color components in the range 0-1
 conv(C) = (column(C)-450.)/100. 
 plot 'DPX_DATA.csv' using (int($0)%17) : (int($0)/17) : (conv(2)) : (conv(3)) : (conv(4)) with rgbimage
```

[image]

**Expanded answer**

There are several ways to pass additional parameters into gnuplot from the command line.  Unfortunately I am not conversant with bash scripting so I can't help with construction of the command line as you show it in your comment.  What I can do is show how to read an environmental variable NAME from inside gnuplot:

```
name = system("printenv NAME")
infile = name . ".csv"
outfile = name . "_RGB_AVGs.png"
set term png
set output outfile
plot infile using ... with rgbimage
```

Comment: This is great.  the data is 10b (0-1023) code values, which I'd like to keep using.  All the values are between 450-600 because it's a fairly homogeneous grey field.  Is the %17 the number of sections across?  and if so, how can I use a variable to represent that, which will be passed from a script that this will live it.

Comment: The expressions for x and y are normal arithmetic.  Sure, you can use a variable name rather than a constant: `N = 17; plot ... using (int(column(0))%N) : (int(column(0))/N) :  (R) : (G) : (B)`. Or N could have been set globally prior to calling this script.

Comment: I can't seem to get the passing of variables.  Here's a test script using a csv file that works:

Comment: #! /bin/bash                                                                                                                            
name="RNST_SDI_20220303_145749.DPX.csv"

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
 set datafile separator "," 
 set rgbmax 1.2
 set title "RGB Average Pixel Values"
 set terminal png size 1920,1080 
 set output'$file_RGB_AVGs.png'
 conv(C) = (column(C)-450.)/100. 
 plot '$name' using (int($0)%17) : (int($0)/17) : (conv(1)) : (conv(2)) : (conv(3)) with rgbimage
 EOFMarker

Comment: I don't know how to format the above to make it legible.  sorry

Comment: See expanded answer.  I don't use bash, so I can't help with that part.

Comment: I'm having problems with the int($0)/17, it keeps returning int(test.sh)%17)

Comment: I suspect the `$0` is being replaced by bash before gnuplot ever sees it.  As I said, I don't do bash scripting so I'm hazy on details there.  But once you are inside gnuplot `$0` is just a shorthand for `column(0)`, so you can use the longer form instead and bash will leave it alone. That's what I showed in my earlier comment. i.e. `int(column(0))` rather than `int($0)`.

Comment: Thank you @Ethan.  I really appreciate the help and appreciate this community